# Convergence Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel iterations and PDE

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How would you do to show that the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel iterations will always converge towards the exact solution of the discrete version of the PDE? I'm given this information:

The solving of following partial derivative equation, in two dimensions:

$v_{xx}(x, y) + v_{yy}(x, y) = v(x, y) + f(x, y)$ ; where $f(x, y) = \sin(\pi x) \sin(\pi y)$

at any point $(x, y)$ of the square domain $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, with the boundary conditions that $v (x, y) = 0$ along all four sides of the square.

The exact answer is $v(x,y) = − \cfrac{sin(\pi x) sin(\pi y)}{1+2\pi^2}$

We also obtain a system of equations for the $v_{i,j}$ by approximating the second derivatives by finite differences :

$(4 + h^2)v_{i,j} − (v_{i-1,j} + v_{i+1,j} + v_{i,j-1} + v_{i,j+1}) = −h^2f_{i,j}$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Converge is only guaranteed for the Gauss-Seidel method if the matrix is strictly diagonally dominant or symmetric positive definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix is strictly diagonally dominant, since $4+h^2 > 1+1+1+1$. This ensures that the iteration matrices, in both Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel methods, have a norm which is less then 1 (you can take for instance the $\infty$-norm), making the sequence convergent. In the case of Jacobi's method, we have that
$$
x^{(n+1)} = \underbrace{D^{-1} b}_{g} - \underbrace{D^{-1}(L+U)}_{C}x^{(n)}=g-C x^{(n)}
$$

and, denoting as $z$ the exact solution,

$$
\|x^{(n+1)}-z\| = \|g-C x^{(n)} - (g-Cz))\|\leq \|C\| \|x^{(n)}-z\|\leq \cdots \leq \|C\|^{n+1}\|x^{(0)}-z\|
$$

Since $\|C\| < 1$, $\lim\|x^{(n)}-z\| \leq \lim \|C\|^n \|x^{(0)}-z\| = 0$.